# What is the trend() function in R

Tags: r

I am reading the [book](https://otexts.com/fpp3/) "Forecasting: Principles and Practice".

And in the [third block](https://otexts.com/fpp3/a-tidy-forecasting-workflow.html) the following code is given:

```
library("forecast")
library("fpp3")

fit <- global_economy %>%
  model(trend_model = tslm(GDP ~ trend()))
```

but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
 object 'trend' not found
```

What is this object?

Comment: What is `global_economy`?

Comment: Maybe provide the output of `dput(global_economy)`, or `dput(head(global_economy))` if it is very large

Comment: Perhaps it would have been useful to note this: "All R examples in the book assume you have loaded the fpp3 package first: `library(fpp3)`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't run the example in the book. You ran `tslm` not `TSLM`.

```r
library("forecast")
library("fpp3")

## You ran this
fit <- global_economy %>%
  model(trend_model = tslm(GDP ~ trend()))
#> Error in eval(term[[1]]): object 'trend' not found

## the example in the book
fit <- global_economy %>%
  model(trend_model = TSLM(GDP ~ trend()))
#> Warning: 7 errors (1 unique) encountered for trend_model
#> [7] 0 (non-NA) cases
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: btw see `?fable::common_xregs` for details on `trend()` and related functions

Comment: thanks, I think your answer is correct, but I can’t check it because I can’t install the fpp3 package, because I can’t install the feasts package on my version 3.4.4 R. Next I have to do this